# Program hanging after its execution--not finishing

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Currently have a shell program that is supposed to gather some general system information for Admin purposes.

ISSUE: after the execution of the program, it seems to hang and never complete. After doing some tinkering I noticed that it appear to be hanging after the call to the "DumpInfo" method

```
# 
# Description: 
# Gather general system info then place info in dumpfile
# 
# Usage: 
# bash getlocal.sh < cmds.txt, cmds.txt is a file with a list of commands to run
#
#

function SepCmds() 
{ 
        LCMD=${ALINE%%|*} 
        REST=${ALINE#*|} 
        WCMD=${REST%%|*} 
        REST=${REST#*|}  
        TAG=${REST%%|*} 

        if [[ $OSTYPE == "MSWin" ]] 
        then 
                CMD="$WCMD" 
        else 
                CMD="$LCMD"
        fi
}

function DumpInfo ()
{ 
        printf '<systeminfo host="%s" type="%s"' "$HOSTNAME" "$OSTYPE"
        printf ' date="%s" time="%s">\n' "$(date '+%F')" "$(date '+%T')"
        readarray CMDS
        for ALINE in "${CMDS[@]}" 
        do 
                #ignore comments 
                if [[ ${ALINE:0:1} == '#' ]] ; then continue ; fi 

                SepCmds

                if [[ ${CMD:0:3} == N/A ]] 
                then 
                        continue
                else 
                        printf "<%s>\n" $TAG
                        $CMD
                        printf "</%s>\n" $TAG
                fi
        done 
        printf "</systeminfo>\n"
}

OSTYPE=$(./osdetect.sh) 
HOSTNM=$(hostname) 
TMPFILE="${HOSTNM}.info"

# gather the info into the tmp file; errors as well 
DumpInfo > $TMPFILE 2>&1
```

Comment: It's waiting for your input at `readarray`.

Comment: You can run it with `bash -x getlocal.sh < cmds.txt` to get a debug trace log (which will be redirected to `TMPFILE`). If that doesn't make the problem obvious, edit your post and include the log

Comment: BTW, see https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete re: the `function` keyword. And I'd **strongly** recommend using a standards-compliant XML library for generating XML. If you want to drive that from bash, see [`pyx`](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html#idm47077139550832) as a format that's easy to parse and generate that can be straightforwardly converted to and from XML. Trying to generate XML with `printf` or other tools that are effectively just doing string concatenation is full of subtle pitfalls; it's almost impossible to do correctly.

Comment: Similarly, running `$CMD` is innately buggy; see [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: Anyhow -- if you have a single, specific problem, build a [mre] -- that means tearing out everything that isn't related to it and showing only the *shortest possible code* that lets someone else reproduce that issue themselves and test whether a fix works.

Comment: This seems to have resolved the issued relaized that I was suppose to run command in conjunction with 'txt' file. Should've read closer my apologies

Comment: I'd suggest deleting the question, as it was resolved in a way that seems unlikely to help others if retained as a knowledge base entry.

Comment: Okay I can do that just one last question, before deletion what would you suggest seeing as $CMD is to buggy?